# How to apply a filter to an image in Image View

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I want to create an image filtering app that applies a random filter to an image in an Image View. I followed a 2014 Apple [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=16). As per Xcode errors and warnings, now I have the following code in ViewController.swift.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    // Create a place to render the filtered image
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)

    @IBAction func applyFilter(_ sender: Any) {
        // Create an image to filter
        let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImageView.image!)

        // Create a random color to pass to a filter
        let randomColor = [kCIInputAngleKey: (Double(arc4random_uniform(314)) / 100)]

        // Apply a filter to the image
        let filteredImage = inputImage?.applyingFilter("CIHueAdjust", parameters: randomColor)

        // Render the filtered image
        let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage!, from: filteredImage!.extent)

        // Reflect the change back in the interface
        //photoImageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: renderedImage!)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[image]
The code before the last commented statement is successfully built. I had to comment the statement because it gave the error `Ambiguous use of init(CGImage)`. The code has no effect currently. It just shows an Image View and a bar button below it (clicking the button does not do anything). Note that my code is slightly different from that of the tutorial, as the tutorial code seems deprecated. Any ideas why the code does not work?

The following is the [code](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/downloads/ViewController.txt) from the original tutorial:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    // Create a place to render the filtered image
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)

    @IBAction func applyFilter(sender: AnyObject) {

        // Create an image to filter
        let inputImage = CIImage(image: photoImageView.image)

        // Create a random color to pass to a filter
        let randomColor = [kCIInputAngleKey: (Double(arc4random_uniform(314)) / 100)]

        // Apply a filter to the image
        let filteredImage = inputImage.imageByApplyingFilter("CIHueAdjust", withInputParameters: randomColor)

        // Render the filtered image
        let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage, fromRect: filteredImage.extent())

        // Reflect the change back in the interface
        photoImageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: renderedImage)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: The Core Image filter name should be "CIHueAdjust", the typo is in your code or just in your question?

Comment: Fixed that. Still does not work!

Comment: Please update your code (the code from @djromero), and either add that it's Swift 2 code (the answers give you other things to change) or give the **current** issue! As it stands, your code posted not only won't build, **it** isn't the issue! A better question/code will help all of us not only help you, but help others. Thanks.

Comment: @dfd i updated the code and question tag.

Comment: If the current code is what you are trying - it couldn't build. You have `let filteredImage = inputImage?.applyingFilter...` inputImage` is - by your code - a `CIImage`, not a `CIFilter`. PLEASE, post actual code!

Comment: Last comment, hopefully pointing you in the right direction. Do *not* try using Core Image filters on a simulator. If you choose to do so, grab a cup of coffee, take a walk, do some laundry, whatever. Generally speaking, something that can happen *instantaneously* on a real device - one with a GPU - will take anywhere from 30 seconds to minutes in the simulator. Why? I just said it - on a device CI uses the GPU and on a simulator it doesn't. thus, you may see a "blank screen" but give it some time and you'll see things if coded correctly.

Comment: Have you tried running through the view inspector? maybe your filter is making the image white on white background and that's why you don't see it. Also try disabling the filter to see if the image effectively displays in the device/simulator without anything

Comment: @dfd thank you. I created the code from scratch.  As you said it doesn't build. No more blank page. The problem is with the last statement.  It says int(CGImage ambiguous)

Comment: I will work on the code and add the one that hopefully works.

Comment: Please see the updated question. What I want is to have my code apply a filter to an image.

Answer (score 1):

Your code shouldn't build.

Once you fix the core image filter name, try replacing:

```
photoImageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: renderedImage!)
```

with:

```
photoImageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: renderedImage!)
//                             ^
//                             |
//                  attention to capitalization
```

Answer (score 0):

There is typo in core image filter name. Also try to run your code in device.